# Padding of size greater than 1 in keras

Tags: padding, convolution, keras, keras-layer

As much as I know in **keras** `border_mode` is used for padding. What I need to know how can I specify a value like `Padding/border_mode=2` in keras? The problem is `border_mode` take only two values: `valid` and `same` So any help?

p.s already asked on data science. But may be it is beta so getting no response :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a ZeroPadding2D layer:

https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding2d

Note: the Keras Convolution2D layer is backed by either the theano.nnet.conv2d or tf.nn.conv2d. The latter doesn't seem to support custom padding (although there's tf.pad for this).

Comment: Should I use padding=(2,2,2,2) to add padding 2 around the image?

Comment: should I use border_mode  = same or valid? in preceding conv layer?

Comment: Use ZeroPadding2D on the input image and after that the conv layer with valid padding (which means no padding in practice).